# Are web designers calling themselves UX designers now a days?

Tags: website-design, ux-field

Are web designer calling themselves as a UX designer now? I have seen that many designer who makes interface for websites or web applications all now calling himself as a UX designer.

Is the **UX designer** term only for the people who deliver the final Photoshop (PSD) Design to developers. Does it matter whether they start to make designs directly in Photoshop or they create low fidelity sketches on paper first then Wire-frame then working prototype (like using Axure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wish we could get past this recurring theme of titles. No - web designers are *not* calling themselves UX designers, any more than UX designers are calling themselves web designers - I don't believe what you have seen can be a generalisation so much as a few *occurrences of note*.

I think the field of UX is still relatively young and evolving - so not had time to really settle and as such there is still this confusion over terms, titles and labels.

I heard Dan Rubin (Creative Director at Moo.com) say recently that when looking at a list of average salaries in London for a person in this field, the list of roles consist of around 30 different titles all for exactly the same thing doing the same job but with a £10,000 difference between the average salaries.

Some people even have a different title internal to a company and another as seen by clients outside the company!

I think it's important not to focus on the title, but on the responsibilities: **Treat the title only with the pinch of salt it deserves.**

Answer (score 8):

Whereas many Web designers call themselves UX designers, many do not have the right UX skills, such as developing and analyzing use cases, creating design requirements based on user research/personas, developing information architecture, creating interaction model, etc. These are core UX activities and "UX" designer needs to be good at.

On the other hand, delivering the final design through Photoshop might not need to be a requirement for a UX designer - that's a requirement for a Web designer, visual designer, or graphic designer. A good UX designer can stop at the wireframing/prototyping and low-fidelity mockups and do not necessarily deliver the final visual design.

Answer (score 1):

Some web designers are using this label. In general, this is overstretching their skill sets away from someone who understands the underlying technology behind a page. Many web designers have poor information architecture skills, tend to less experience in business analysis and or human behavior analysis knowledge.

A good web designer adds that final layer of information structure and usability to a site... based on the requirements outlined by a UX designer or team.

Just because I can outline a page in wireframing software or even in Photoshop, does not make me a web designer.